# ServiceStack - Defining routes for resources with multiple keys

Tags: c#, servicestack

Which option is best for defining routes when dealing with resources that have multiple keys in ServiceStack?

For some context, I have the need to get all transactions for a given customer. A unique customer can be identified by either an id number or a card number. I have created a request DTO as follows...

```
public class GetCustomerTransactions : IReturn<List<Transactions>>
{
    public int? CustomerId { get; set; }
    public long? CardNumber { get; set; }
}
```

The route is currently defined as...

```
[Route("/customers{" + nameof(CustomerId) + "}/transactions", "GET")]
```

Ideally I am hoping for something like this...

```
[Route("/customers{" + nameof(CustomerId) + "}/transactions", "GET")]
[Route("/customers{" + nameof(CardNumber) + "}/transactions", "GET")]
```

Currently I have three options.

**Option 1**
Create two routes as follows. The first route will allow transactions to be found using the customer id. The second route allows transactions to be found using either customer id or card number. The problem here is someone could populate both values and potentially return misinformation if the two codes happen to not correspond to the same person.

```
[Route("/customers{" + nameof(CustomerId) + "}/transactions", "GET")]
[Route("/customers/transactions", "GET")]
```

**Option 2**
Force the clients to look up the customer using a different endpoint and return the customer id as part of the reponse. Then define the route using only customer id and remove the card number from the request DTO.

**Option 3**
Change the request DTO to have one field called "CustomerIdOrCardNumber" and then implement logic to determine if the value passed in was a customer id or card number

I am open to other options as well. Not sure the best approach for this type of scenario.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wouldn't maintain multiple routes for each customer resource as it unnecessarily complicates your API and multiplies your routes for each Service.

I'd only maintain Customer Id for your Customer Resources that you want to maintain semantic URL structure for, e.g:

```
[Route("/customers/{" +  nameof(Id) + "}")]
public class GetCustomer : IReturn<Customer>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

[Route("/customers/{" +  nameof(Id) + "}/transactions")]
public class GetCustomerTransactions : IReturn<List<Transactions>>
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}
```

Then I'd have just a "discovery" Service where you could resolve a `Customer` using different attributes, e.g:

```
[Route("/customers")]
public class GetCustomers : IReturn<List<Customer>>
{
    public int[] CustomerIds { get; set; }
    public long[] CardNumbers { get; set; }
    public string[] Emails { get; set; }
}
```

Although my preference would be to use [AutoQuery](http://docs.servicestack.net/autoquery-rdbms) since it greatly reduces the effort to create Search Services like this, e.g:

```
[Route("/customers/search")]
public class SearchCustomers : QueryDb<Customer>
{
    public int[] CustomerIds { get; set; }
    public long[] CardNumbers { get; set; }
    public string[] Emails { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: is AutoQuery meant to be used in this context as an end point for a client api? My brief experimentation with it made it feel like it was supposed to drive a front end for ad hoc exploration of data.

Comment: @IronicMuffin It's a normal ServiceStack Service that's implemented efficiently and maintains a similar Service Contract to how it would be developed manually whilst allowing its implementation to be completley overridden. The fact that it can easily serve an [automatic data-driven UI like AutoQuery Viewer](https://github.com/ServiceStack/Admin) doesn't detract from it's usefulness to rapidly develop web services with it.

Answer (score 1):

You are performing to different operations so you should have two routes in my opinion, specially since an int can be converted to a long so there could be some collisions.

Something like:

```
[Route("/customers/ById/{" + nameof(CustomerId) + "}/transactions", "GET")]
[Route("/customers/ByCardNumber/{" + nameof(CardNumber) + "}/transactions", "GET")]
```

Or:

```
[Route("/customers{" + nameof(CustomerId) + "}/transactionsByCId", "GET")]
[Route("/customers{" + nameof(CardNumber) + "}/transactionsByCN", "GET")]
```

I favor the first one but you get the point.